# My app always crashes when starting a second activity within an onClick method

Tags: android, button, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener

My app has two activities: MainActivity and DrawingActivity. In MainActivity it is showed a button and in DrawingActivity it is showed a camera preview on a GLSurfaceview. The idea is that, when you launch the app, first you run the MainActivity, and when you press the button, you jump to the DrawingActivity where the camera is initialized and the camera preview is showed. For that I have tried to define an `intent` object within an `onClickLIstener` callback attached to the button. The issue is that every time I press the button, my app crashes by calling private void `stopEglSurfaceLocked()` method on `GLSurfaceView` class.

The funny thing is that if I define the `intent` outside the `onClick` method, everything works fine.

Here are some relevante code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btnStart;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawingActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        }
    });

  }
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.opengltest.AssetsCache"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:largeHeap="true">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.opengltest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="com.example.opengltest.DrawingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage()' on a null object reference
09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981):    at com.example.opengltest.DrawingActivity.onNewFrame(DrawingActivity.java:526)
09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981):    at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView$StereoRendererHelper.onDrawFrame(CardboardView.java:289)
09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981):    at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView$RendererHelper.onDrawFrame(CardboardView.java:598)
09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

IMPORTANT:
Although it seems that there is something wrong in the DrawingActivity class, that is not true. If I made the Drawing Activity class the main class, so it is called at the beginning (without intent), everthing goes ok. Definitively DrawingActivity class is not the culprit, everything seems to indicate that the problem is in the intent. I am doing something such that the DrawingActivity class is not running as it is supposed to run.

Comment: can your share your error log

Comment: are you sure the crash is because of starting the second activty or something to do with first ? please share the crash log

Comment: can you share your DrawingActivity and your errors log ?

Comment: I posted the error log.  I understand the error, null pointer, what I don't understand is why this error only happens when I start the activity within the onclicklisterner callback ...

Comment: `09-01 12:03:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(13981): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage()' on a null object reference` The error comes from your DrawingActivity class, please post this class too.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the `onClickListener` as :

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 ...
```

It's incorrect, use it as below to handle a click on a View in Android :

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 ...
```

Read more : [View.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

And simply start your intent inside the `onClick` method :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: mmm thanks for the reply, but the problem persists even with your suggested changes :(

Comment: The error is indicating a problem in your DrawingActivity, please post your DrawingActivity code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use try/catch/finally block to start the DrawingActivity and finish the MainActivity :

```
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try
            {
                //Try starting the Drawing activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DrawingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //A problem occured, check Logcat
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                //DrawingActivity successfully started
                //So, finish the MainActivity
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, so this has nothing to do with your intent, we need the code for the DrawingActivity class? Just share it so that we can help you ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share this code, I know it is too bad ... However, I dont think the problem is there. As I stated, if I move the intent definition and the startactivity method outside the onClickListenerMethod, it would work fine. No problem with the DrawingActivity, in fact this class have been working for many months as the main activity with no issues...